# how to convert string to int in visual studios c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
myString = txtEmployeeID.Text;// storing what the user enters into myString.

tempObject = new EmployeeClass();

tempObject.getAccessID(myString);
```

***I get an error on this line***

How do I fix line 3?

Comment: what error you got

Comment: you need to show the method getAccessID and the error details

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to number (an integer probably) as *that is what* the getAccessID method *expects*.

```
myString = txtEmployeeID.Text;
tempObject = new EmployeeClass();
int number = 0;
bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(myString, out number);
if (isNumber) tempObject.getAccessID(number);
```

Tip: Always give functions/methods the parameters they expect, in the correct datatype.

---

An alternate method is to only accept digits in the textbox:

```
private void txtEmployeeID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Make it only accept `> int.MinValue` and `< int.MaxValue` then you can safely do this:

```
tempObject.getAccessID(Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text));
```